# If "modules/mod_rewrite.so" is commented out, will show "Internal Server Error"

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know if the following code have be commented out

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

the mod_rewrite will not work

.

And if the ".htaccess" existed and code include following,

```
RewriteEngine On
```

the browser will show me "Internal Server Error"

.

But I cannot remove or edit httpd.conf or .htaccess

I can just add some rule to .htaccess but cannot change existed rules

.

So, can I make the RewriteEngine "Off" when "modules/mod_rewrite.so" is commented  out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add your rules in an `<IfModule>` block:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    # your rules
</IfModule>
```

This way, if mod_rewrite isn't loaded, the rules won't be applied and you won't get any 500 "Internal Server Error"